# How do I retrieve an error string from WSAGetLastError()?

Tags: c, winapi, sockets, winsock

I'm porting some sockets code from Linux to Windows.

In Linux, I could use `strerror()` to convert an errno code into a human-readable string.

MSDN documentation shows equivalent strings for each error code returned from `WSAGetLastError()`, but I don't see anything about how to retrieve those strings.  Will `strerror()` work here too?

How can I retrieve human-readable error strings from Winsock?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

As the documentation for [`WSAGetLastError`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms741580%28VS.85%29.aspx) says you can use [`FormatMessage`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms679351%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) to obtain a text version of the error message.

You need to set `FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM` in the `dwFlags` parameter and pass the error code as the `dwMessage` parameter.

Comment: Thanks--I just discovered that myself.  I need to remember to look at the online MSDN (vs. the off-line copy installed on my laptop!).

Answer (score 47):

```
wchar_t *s = NULL;
FormatMessageW(FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER | FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM | FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS, 
               NULL, WSAGetLastError(),
               MAKELANGID(LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_DEFAULT),
               (LPWSTR)&s, 0, NULL);
fprintf(stderr, "%S\n", s);
LocalFree(s);
```

Comment: The `&s` argument must be casted to LPTSTR here because this function uses a hack here with this parameter returning a pointer to string as a string.

Comment: Only if you also change FormatMessageW to FormatMessage.  Otherwise, you may need to cast instead to LPWSTR, depending on the settings in your Visual Studio project.

Comment: I edited the answer to include the cast to `LPWSTR`, otherwise the compiler fails

Answer (score 12):

A slightly simpler version of mxcl's answer, which removes the need for malloc/free and the risks implicit therein, and which handles the case where no message text is available (since Microsoft doesn't document what happens then):

```
int
   err;

char
   msgbuf [256];   // for a message up to 255 bytes.


msgbuf [0] = '\0';    // Microsoft doesn't guarantee this on man page.

err = WSAGetLastError ();

FormatMessage (FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM | FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS,   // flags
               NULL,                // lpsource
               err,                 // message id
               MAKELANGID (LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_DEFAULT),    // languageid
               msgbuf,              // output buffer
               sizeof (msgbuf),     // size of msgbuf, bytes
               NULL);               // va_list of arguments

if (! *msgbuf)
   sprintf (msgbuf, "%d", err);  // provide error # if no string available
```