# How to get getaddrinfo() error code?

Tags: c++, sockets, winapi, winsock

From the [Winsock Reference page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms738520(v=vs.85).aspx), it said:

> getaddrinfo function
>
> Return value
>
> Success returns zero. Failure returns a nonzero Windows Sockets error code, as **found in the Windows Sockets Error Codes**.
>
> Use the gai_strerror function to print error messages based on **the EAI codes returned by the getaddrinfo function**. The gai_strerror function is provided for compliance with IETF recommendations, but it is not thread safe. **Therefore, use of traditional Windows Sockets functions such as WSAGetLastError is recommended.**

It said the EAI error codes can be found in the [Windows Sockets Error Codes page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740668(v=vs.85).aspx), but I cannot see any EAI code in that page, such as EAI_AGAIN, EAI_BADFLAGS, etc...

For Windows, the correct way to get the code is to check if `getaddrinfo` returns a nonzero value, then call `WSAGetLastError` to get the code?

Comment: Ya you use WSAGetLastError and here's how to retrieve the corresponding string: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3400922/how-do-i-retrieve-an-error-string-from-wsagetlasterror?rq=1

Comment: 'It said the EAI error codes can be found in the Windows Sockets Error Codes page'. No it didn't. It provided a mapping *on that MSDN page.*

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the standard approach is to use `getaddrinfo` and if it returns nonzero, then call `WSAGetLastError` to retrieve the Winsock error code.

You can then use [`FormatMessage`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms679351(v=VS.85).aspx) to convert the error code into a human-readable string, by passing `FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM` as the `dwFlags` parameter, and the error code as the `dwMessage` parameter. You can see the documentation for this behaviour [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms679351(v=VS.85).aspx), in the table under `FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM`. Asesh has pointed out [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3400922/how-do-i-retrieve-an-error-string-from-wsagetlasterror?rq=1) which has some sample code demonstrating this.

You can use `gai_strerror` like on a Linux system, but [according to MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms738518(v=vs.85).aspx) (search for `gai_strerror`), it's not thread safe so `FormatMessage` is preferred.

Alternatively you can just manually cross-reference them with [this nice big list](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740668(v=vs.85).aspx).