# IPv6 Server in c - recvfrom failed

Tags: c, server, ipv6, winsock2, recvfrom

i have written a small c-program for an IPv6 server with winsock2.h When I run the program in Visual Studio, I get the following message all the time: recvfrom failed

I just can't find the error in the recvfrom function. Maybe someone can see why my program does not work at this point, thanks!  :-)

Best regards,
Ken

```
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN

#include <winsock2.h>
#include <ws2tcpip.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#pragma comment(lib, "Ws2_32.lib")

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    SOCKET server_socket;
    struct sockaddr_in6 server_addr, client_addr;
    socklen_t client_len;
    char buf[1024];
    char clientIP[256];

    WSADATA data;
    WORD version = MAKEWORD(2, 2);
    if (WSAStartup(version, &data) == SOCKET_ERROR) {

        printf("WSASStartup failed\n");
        WSACleanup();
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    server_socket = socket(AF_INET6, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
    if (server_socket == -1) {

        printf("creating socket failed\n");
        WSACleanup();
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    else {

        printf("creating socket successful\n");
    }

    memset(&server_addr, 0, sizeof(server_addr));
    server_addr.sin6_addr = in6addr_any;
    server_addr.sin6_family = AF_INET6;
    server_addr.sin6_port = htons(5001);

    if (bind(server_socket, (const struct sockaddr*) & server_addr,
        sizeof(server_addr)) == -1) {

        printf("bind socket failed\n");
        WSACleanup();
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    else {

        printf("bind socket successful\n");
    }

    while (1) {

        memset(&client_addr, 0, sizeof(client_addr));
        memset(buf, 0, sizeof(buf));

        if (recvfrom(server_socket, (char*)buf, 1024, 0,
            (struct sockaddr*) & client_addr,
            sizeof(client_addr)) == -1) {

            printf("recvfrom failed\n");
            WSACleanup();
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        else {

            printf("recvfrom successful");
        }

        printf("%s\n", buf);
        printf("IP: %s\n", inet_ntop(AF_INET6, &client_addr.sin6_addr,
            clientIP, 256));
    }

    closesocket(server_socket);

    WSACleanup();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should print out a detailed error message. See [How do I retrieve an error string from WSAGetLastError()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3400922/how-do-i-retrieve-an-error-string-from-wsagetlasterror) for examples.

Comment: The winsock2 `recvfrom` function returns `SOCKET_ERROR` when there's an error (so don't use -1). To find out why a winsock2 function fails, called `WSAGetLastError()`. What does it return?

Comment: The last argument to recvfrom() is a pointer to an int containing the length of the object pointed to by the fifth argument.  You passed (essentially) an int as the sixth argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are misusing `recvfrom()`.  The `fromlen` parameter expects to receive an `int*` pointer that points to an `int`, which on input specifies the byte size of the `sockaddr` buffer being passed in the `from` parameter, and on output receives the byte size of the `sockaddr` written to the `from` buffer.

There are also some other minor bugs in your code:

- `WSAStartup()` does not return `SOCKET_ERROR` on failure, it returns an actual error code.
- you are ignoring the return value of `recvfrom()`, which tells you how many bytes were actually written to your `buf`.  You are assuming `buf` is always null-terminated when passing it to `printf("%s")`, but that is not guaranteed.  You are zeroing out `buf` to initialize it with null terminators, which is fine if `recvfrom()` receives a datagram containing less than 1024 bytes. But if it receives a datagram with exactly 1024 bytes than all of your null terminators will be overwritten and there will be no terminator left for `printf()` to find (if `recvfrom()` receives a datagram with more than 1024 bytes, it will fail with a `WSAEMSGSIZE` error, which is not a fatal error but you are treating it as if it were). Rather than rely on any null terminators at all, you can pass the return value of `recvfrom()` to `printf()` for the buffer size. No need to waste overhead zeroing out what `recvfrom()` will overwrite.

Try this instead:

```c
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN

#include <winsock2.h>
#include <ws2tcpip.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#pragma comment(lib, "Ws2_32.lib")

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    SOCKET server_socket;
    struct sockaddr_in6 server_addr, client_addr;
    int client_len, num_recvd;
    char buf[1024];
    char clientIP[256];

    WSADATA data;
    WORD version = MAKEWORD(2, 2);

    int errCode = WSAStartup(version, &data);
    if (errCode != 0) {
        printf("WSAStartup failed, error %d\n", errCode);
        WSACleanup();
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    server_socket = socket(AF_INET6, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP);
    if (server_socket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
        errCode = WSAGetLastError();
        printf("creating socket failed, error %d\n", errCode);
        WSACleanup();
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    printf("creating socket successful\n");

    memset(&server_addr, 0, sizeof(server_addr));
    server_addr.sin6_addr = in6addr_any;
    server_addr.sin6_family = AF_INET6;
    server_addr.sin6_port = htons(5001);

    if (bind(server_socket, (struct sockaddr*) &server_addr, sizeof(server_addr)) == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        errCode = WSAGetLastError();
        printf("bind socket failed, error %d\n", errCode);
        closesocket(server_socket);
        WSACleanup();
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    printf("bind socket successful\n");

    while (1) {

        client_len = sizeof(client_addr);

        num_recvd = recvfrom(server_socket, buf, sizeof(buf), 0, (struct sockaddr*) &client_addr, &client_len);
        if (num_recvd == SOCKET_ERROR) {
            errCode = WSAGetLastError();
            if (errCode != WSAEMSGSIZE) {
                printf("recvfrom failed, error %d\n", errCode);
                closesocket(server_socket);
                WSACleanup();
                return EXIT_FAILURE;
            }
            printf("recvfrom truncated a datagram larger than %u bytes!\n", sizeof(buf));
            num_recvd = sizeof(buf);
        }
        else {
            printf("recvfrom successful\n");
        }

        printf("%.*s\n", num_recvd, buf);
        printf("IP: %s\n", inet_ntop(AF_INET6, &client_addr.sin6_addr, clientIP, 256));
    }

    closesocket(server_socket);
    WSACleanup();

    return 0;
}
```